# Office 365 forbidden 403

Tags: office365connectors, microsoft-teams

When I try to access Office 365 Group Connectors, either in the Outlook web or via Teams app, I receive an error message similar to the one below. Is there some permission missing from my account that prevents me from using connectors?

```
:-(
Something went wrong.
Message=The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.:ErrorDetails=Operation=GetJoinedGroups:HttpStatusCode=Forbidden:ErrorCode=ErrorAccessDenied:ErrorMessage=Access to OData is disabled.:InnerErrorType=:InnerErrorMessage=:CorrectiveAction=NoAction
RequestId: 2988daef-51e0-4ccb-9145-109b0f806bf8
Server: DM5PR02MB2409
Date: 2016-11-17 16:10:36 -0600
```

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. We are investigating.

Answer (score 1):

Please escalate this issue to Office 365 Support. This is related to a setting your Tenant Admin has configured.